# MongoDB collection toArray() length is 20 less than collection.count()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-shell

I am using mongoDB version 3.6.3 on a ubuntu operating system.
I have created a collection with 100 records

To manipulate the data on the mongo shell I assign cursor like below

`cur = db.dummyData.find({}, {_id: 0})`

now the `cur.count()` is 100 but `cur.toArray().length` is 80.

I not sure why this is happening. I have tried with bunch of different collections toArray() length is always 20 less than the actual count.

Would appreciate any help to understand this behavior.

Comment: And what happen if you go through that cursor with .foreach() and count rounds? I guess you will get that 100.

Comment: Tried that as well, foreach is also going to 80.

Comment: The current 3.6 version is 3.6.17, you should upgrade to that version first .

Comment: Docs: `.count does not perform the query but instead counts the results that would be returned by the query.` Use `.itcount()`

Comment: count() is giving me the output i expect. My problem is while iterating over the documents I am able to iterate over only 80 documents not 100

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB keeps a running count of documents for each collection which is updated for each insert/delete operation.  Some occurrences such a hard shutdown can result in this number in the metadata differing from the actual collection.

The `cursor.count()` function queries the MongoDB asking for this number from the metadata without fetching any documents, so it is very fast.  The `cursor.itcount()` function will actually fetch the documents, so it will run slower, but will always return an accurate count.

To correct the count in the collections metadata, run `db.collectionName.validate(true)` on the collection in question from the mongo shell.

Comment: count() function is giving me accurate result but when I assign the cursor to a variable and iterate over it, I can see only 80 documents not 100.

Comment: What makes you think there are 100 documents if the cursor only returns 80?

Comment: ```.count()``` is returning 100. but when I iterate over the cursor I get only 80 documents

Comment: And since `count()` is known to be inaccurate at times, what makes you think it is correct this time?  Try using `itcount()` which actually counts the documents instead of returning the metadata, and if they don't agree, run `validate` on the collection